# Can Oracle select updated rows in a single query?

Tags: oracle, select

Can Oracle select updated rows in one shot? If yes, how?

Using PostgreSQL, one can write:

```
WITH updated AS (
    UPDATE MY_SCHEDULE
        set STATUS='done'
    where STATUS='not done' 
        RETURNING STATUS)
SELECT updated.*
    FROM updated;
```

Comment: Let me clarify my question. I need it in a one line, simple, pure sql statement, for instance, in an interactive command line mode, not embedding the query in any programming languages where you can simply store the intermediary value in a variable and then utilize it later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `returning` clause of the [update statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5) to return values from the updated rows into host or PL/SQL variables.

Here's a quick demo on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5a2d6ad6185c550a51da0e2e39877ec), I use `bulk collect into` and the collection type `sys.odciNumberList` because I expect my update to effect multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

Various language APIs support a RETURNING INTO clause, e.g. in Python cx_Oracle:

```py
# The RETURNING INTO bind variable is a string
dept_name = cursor.var(str)

cursor.execute("""
        update departments set
            location_id = :loc_id
        where department_id = :dept_id
        returning department_name into :dept_name""",
        loc_id=1700, dept_id=50, dept_name=dept_name)
print(dept_name.getvalue())     # will print ['Shipping']
```

See [DML RETURNING Bind Variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#dml-returning-bind-variables)